# Why Adobe Acrobat is asking for Proxy server username password

Tags: windows-7, installation, adobe-acrobat

I have installed trial version of Adobe acrobat on my machine. Before launching it asks to sign in with Adobe Id. After successfully signing in it asks to enter proxy server username and password like this:

Message: "Please provide your proxy server username and password"

[image]

I have installed Adobe Acrobat last month on a different machine and at that time it only asks for Adobe Id to sign in.

Any reason why it is asking now. Is there any setting on this new machine that I have to check or some update by Adobe?

Comment: Is your system configured to use a proxy? You can find this from Internet Settings in Control Panel. On the Connections tab, click LAN settings.

Comment: @mtak No, system is not configured to use proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a proxy related issue.

I have installed [Microsoft Forefront TMG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Forefront_Threat_Management_Gateway) to fix this issue.